# Assertion error on host name when connecting to IBM queue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cucumber, jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to IBM queue for my cucumber tests, but getting the below assertion error. If we bypass the assertion by running the via feature file or removing assertions from vm options, it works fine, configuration is for java 17.

```
java.lang.AssertionError
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.WMQPropertyContext.getStringProperty(WMQPropertyContext.java:390)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.StringableProperty.resolve(StringableProperty.java:137)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.internal.StringableProperty.jsonIfy(StringableProperty.java:129)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.internal.WMQSession.toJson(WMQSession.java:2162)
        at com.ibm.msg.client.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl.toJson(JmsSessionImpl.java:6097)
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.MQSession.toString(MQSession.java:1476)
        at java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4218)
        at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:502)
        at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.send(JmsTemplate.java:584)
```

Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Tried bypassing assertion in pom xml configuration and in command line mvn clean install.
Still the assertion error persists.

Comment: Update your question with the version of the MQ JAR files you are using and the code that goes with the error.

Answer (score 0):

The is an IBM MQ APAR and a fix that matches this problem:
[IT42506](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IT42506)